# Getting an import error on Beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I am trying to understand web parsing and I am a beginner. I have installed beautiful soup and following is my code

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

source_code = urllib.request.urlopen('https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface/').read()
soup = bs.Beautifulsoup(source_code, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

yet when I run this i am getting an error

```
 File "C:\Users\my dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
from .builder import builder_registry


 File "C:\Users\my dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from bs4.element import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'CharsetMetaAttributeValue'
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Not sure if matters, but you have a space in your install path. Python typically wants to install at C:\Python3